# Show view is the same for all my linked_to items listed in the index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a site I'm working on that has many projects. Each project then has many project updates. The project updates for each specific project are displayed in an index view which links from each listed project update to its individual project update show page.

The problem right now is that when on the project update index page no matter which of the project I click on it take me to the show view of the first project update. Why is it not taking me to the respective project update show view?

I have an index view like so:

```
    <%= provide(:title, 'All Project Updates') %>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                       </br>

                      <% @projectUpdates.each do |projectUpdate| %>

                      <div class="update-listing">
                          <div><%= projectUpdate.featured_image %></div>
                          <div><%= link_to projectUpdate.title, project_update_path %></div>
                          <div><%= projectUpdate.description %></div>
                        </br>
                        </br>
                      </div>

                      <% end %>

            </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my show view:

```
<%= provide(:title, @projectUpdate.project.npo.name+"Updates | "+@projectUpdate.project.name) %> 
<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
    <h1><%= @projectUpdate.project.npo.name+"Updates | "+@projectUpdate.project.name %></h1>
    <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-7 large-8 columns">

            <div class="random-text">
                        <%= @projectUpdate.title %></br>
                        <%= @projectUpdate.description %></br>

                <% if false %> <%= image_tag @projectUpdate.project_image %> 
                <%= link_to project_update_path(@projectUpdate) %><% end %>
                </br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <%= link_to "Back", :back, class:"btn btn-default return-project-button" %>
                <% if can? :manage, @projectUpdate.project %>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_update_path(@projectUpdate), class:"btn btn-default edit-update-button" %> 
                <%= link_to 'Delete', @projectUpdate, class:"btn btn-default delete-update-button", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>
<% end %>
```

These are the index & show actions in my project update controller:

```
def index
      @projectUpdates = ProjectUpdate.where(:project_id => params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
      end
   end

   def show
      @projectUpdate = ProjectUpdate.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
      end
   end
```

Some relevant routes to make sense of the code:

```
get 'all_project_updates/:id' => 'project_updates#index', as: 'all_project_updates'
resources :project_updates
resources :projects
```

I tried changing:

```
          <div><%= link_to projectUpdate.title, project_update_path %></div>
```

to

```
          <div><%= link_to projectUpdate.title, project_update_path(@projectUpdate) %></div>
```

But that led to blank show page's.

I am relatively new to programming so some simple explanation would be appreciated.

I think I am not properly passing the parameter in my controller to select individual project updates to display but not sure about this. Thoughts?

rake routes output:

```
                         Prefix Verb     URI Pattern
Controller#Action
               new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)
users/sessions#new
                   user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)
users/sessions#create
           destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)
users/sessions#destroy
        user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)
users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
         user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format
users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
                  user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)
devise/passwords#create
              new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)
devise/passwords#new
             edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)
devise/passwords#edit
                                PATCH    /users/password(.:format)
devise/passwords#update
                                PUT      /users/password(.:format)
devise/passwords#update
       cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)
users/registrations#cancel
              user_registration POST     /users(.:format)
users/registrations#create
          new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)
users/registrations#new
         edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)
users/registrations#edit
                                PATCH    /users(.:format)
users/registrations#update
                                PUT      /users(.:format)
users/registrations#update
                                DELETE   /users(.:format)
users/registrations#destroy
              user_confirmation POST     /users/confirmation(.:format)
devise/confirmations#create
          new_user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation/new(.:format)
devise/confirmations#new
                                GET      /users/confirmation(.:format)
devise/confirmations#show
                           root GET      /
pages#home
                 login_any_user POST     /login_any_user(.:format)
users#login_redirect
                 user_dashboard GET      /users/:id/user_dashboard(.:format)
users#user_dashboard
                  user_settings GET      /users/:id/settings(.:format)
users#settings
           reactivate_user_page GET      /users/:id/reactivate(.:format)
users#reactivate
                reactivate_user POST     /users/:id/reactivate(.:format)
users#reactivate_user
                new_transaction POST     /transactions/new/:id(.:format)
transactions#new
                  npo_dashboard GET      /npos/:id/npo_dashboard(.:format)
npos#npo_dashboard
                    my_projects GET      /npos/:id/my_projects(.:format)
projects#manage_projects
                admin_dashboard GET      /admin_dashboard(.:format)
users#admin_dashboard
                          about GET      /about(.:format)
pages#about
                     howitworks GET      /howitworks(.:format)
pages#howitworks
                        contact GET      /contact(.:format)
pages#contact
                        sponsor GET      /sponsor(.:format)
pages#sponsor
                          deals GET      /deals(.:format)
pages#deals
                         refund GET      /refund(.:format)
transactions#refund
            all_project_updates GET      /all_project_updates/:id(.:format)
project_updates#index
                          pages GET      /pages(.:format)
pages#index
                                POST     /pages(.:format)
pages#create
                       new_page GET      /pages/new(.:format)
pages#new
                      edit_page GET      /pages/:id/edit(.:format)
pages#edit
                           page GET      /pages/:id(.:format)
pages#show
                                PATCH    /pages/:id(.:format)
pages#update
                                PUT      /pages/:id(.:format)
pages#update
                                DELETE   /pages/:id(.:format)
pages#destroy
                       projects GET      /projects(.:format)
projects#index
                                POST     /projects(.:format)
projects#create
                    new_project GET      /projects/new(.:format)
projects#new
                   edit_project GET      /projects/:id/edit(.:format)
projects#edit
                        project GET      /projects/:id(.:format)
projects#show
                                PATCH    /projects/:id(.:format)
projects#update
                                PUT      /projects/:id(.:format)
projects#update
                                DELETE   /projects/:id(.:format)
projects#destroy
                           npos GET      /npos(.:format)
npos#index
                                POST     /npos(.:format)
npos#create
                        new_npo GET      /npos/new(.:format)
npos#new
                       edit_npo GET      /npos/:id/edit(.:format)
npos#edit
                            npo GET      /npos/:id(.:format)
npos#show
                                PATCH    /npos/:id(.:format)
npos#update
                                PUT      /npos/:id(.:format)
npos#update
                                DELETE   /npos/:id(.:format)
npos#destroy
                   transactions GET      /transactions(.:format)
transactions#index
                                POST     /transactions(.:format)
transactions#create
                                GET      /transactions/new(.:format)
transactions#new
               edit_transaction GET      /transactions/:id/edit(.:format)
transactions#edit
                    transaction GET      /transactions/:id(.:format)
transactions#show
                                PATCH    /transactions/:id(.:format)
transactions#update
                                PUT      /transactions/:id(.:format)
transactions#update
                                DELETE   /transactions/:id(.:format)
transactions#destroy
                          users GET      /users(.:format)
users#index
                                POST     /users(.:format)
users#create
                       new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)
users#new
                      edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)
users#edit
                           user GET      /users/:id(.:format)
users#show
                                PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)
users#update
                                PUT      /users/:id(.:format)
users#update
                                DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)
users#destroy
                     categories GET      /categories(.:format)
categories#index
                                POST     /categories(.:format)
categories#create
                   new_category GET      /categories/new(.:format)
categories#new
                  edit_category GET      /categories/:id/edit(.:format)
categories#edit
                       category GET      /categories/:id(.:format)
categories#show
                                PATCH    /categories/:id(.:format)
categories#update
                                PUT      /categories/:id(.:format)
categories#update
                                DELETE   /categories/:id(.:format)
categories#destroy
                project_updates GET      /project_updates(.:format)
project_updates#index
                                POST     /project_updates(.:format)
project_updates#create
             new_project_update GET      /project_updates/new(.:format)
project_updates#new
            edit_project_update GET      /project_updates/:id/edit(.:format)
project_updates#edit
                 project_update GET      /project_updates/:id(.:format)
project_updates#show
                                PATCH    /project_updates/:id(.:format)
project_updates#update
                                PUT      /project_updates/:id(.:format)
project_updates#update
                                DELETE   /project_updates/:id(.:format)
project_updates#destroy
                      s3_create POST     /s3/upload(.:format)
media_files#s3_create
                      s3_delete DELETE   /s3/delete/:id(.:format)
media_files#s3_delete
create_or_update_avatar_from_s3 POST     /s3/avatar(.:format)
media_files#create_or_update_avatar_from_s3
          delete_avatar_from_s3 DELETE   /s3/avatar/:id(.:format)
media_files#delete_avatar_from_s3
```

Comment: Try like this `<%= link_to projectUpdate.title, project_update_path(projectUpdate) %>`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Could you explain a bit why though? I'd like to understand what is actually happening if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index, you need to change:

```
<div><%= link_to projectUpdate.title, project_update_path %></div>
```

to:

```
<div><%= link_to projectUpdate.title, project_update_path(projectUpdate) %></div>
```

As you can see in your `rake routes` output, you have this line:

```
project_update GET      /project_updates/:id(.:format)     project_updates#show
```

This means you have a named route `project_update`, joining any path like `/project_updates/:id(.:format)` to ProjectUpdatedController's show action.

Now have a look at: `/project_updates/:id(.:format)`. In general, anything starting with a colon within those paths is a param. Also, anything in bracket is optional. Hence from this path, you can say that it is impossible to build correct path without an id.

Rails routing provides you with helpers to generate urls, they are always named `<name_of_your_named_route>_path` and `<name_of_your_named_route>_url`. It is rather a good practice to always use the first one. Its only purpose is to return the correct path.

In case of `project_update_path`, it is impossible to build the path without an id param. those `url_helpers` accepts any number of arguments, which are being treated as params. They can have a form of hash:

```
project_update_path(id: 5)    #=> /project_updates/5
```

pure values:

```
project_update_path(5)     #=> /projects_updates/5
```

or mix of those:

```
project_update_path(5, format: 'html')   #=> /projects_updates/5.html
```

Pure values are mapped to params in order they appear in a path:

```
project_update_path(5, 'html')   #=> /projects_updates/5.html
```

If you pass params not included in a path, they are added to GET query:

```
project_update_path(5, 'html', foo: 'bar')   #=> /projects_updates/5.html?foo=bar
```

If this is not enough, rails is clever enough to accept ActiveRecord object as an argument. It will then execute `to_path` method on this object and use it insted. Default implementation of `to_param` is to return model's id, hence you can do:

```
project_update = ProjectUpdate.find(5) 
project_update_path(project_update)   #=> /projects_updates/5
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Could you explain a bit why though? I'd like to understand what is actually happening if possible

Comment: I will, but there is one more unknown for me. Could you update your question with the output of `rake routes` (I would expect your code to raise an exception)

Comment: You want to see rake routes output before the change or after? or both?

Comment: @user3597950 - The change above will not change the output of `rake routes`

Comment: Hmm no exception is raised. Just all the routes are shown.

Comment: @user3597950 - I'm still confused, you should get an exception. Another question, what will happen if you open rails console and type `app.project_update_path`?

Comment: I get an error. By the way I have this in my project Model -  has_many :updates, class_name: "ProjectUpdate" Is that something that may be confusing you?

Comment: This is the console error: irb(main):001:0> app.project_update_path
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :contro
ller=>"project_updates"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54199/discussion-between-broisatse-and-user3597950).